# How to set the precision of a 'rug::float' above the i32 that the precision parm takes in rust

Tags: rust, precision, rust-cargo, gmp

I am using rug a cargo create for the rust programing language to calculate very No suggestions large numbers, rug is supposed to be arbitrary precision however when i go to set the prescion of my `rug::Float` using `rug::Float::with_val (prec i32: [some value larger than i32 can hold], val Integer: some rug::Integer)` rust panics sbecause my precision is too high see code below

```rustc
fn main () {
    use rug::{Complete, Float, Integer};
    let _num = Integer::from(103204)
    let _float = Float::with_val(10000000000, _num

}
```

the result of this unsuprisiling is a panic as my precistion, the first pram to with_val is greater than what a i32 can hold, however rug is souposed to be arbtrary precision, so my qustion is how can I create a float that has higher precision than the max value of i32?

Answer (score 3):

There is a max amount of precision supported by the [underlying MPFR library](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-2.3.1/mpfr.html)

> A floating-point number or float for short, is an arbitrary precision significand (also called mantissa) with a limited precision exponent....

> The precision is the number of bits used to represent the significand of a floating-point number; the corresponding C data type is mp_prec_t. The precision can be any integer between MPFR_PREC_MIN and **MPFR_PREC_MAX**. In the current implementation, MPFR_PREC_MIN is equal to 2.

And it looks to be u32::MAX see the [doc here](https://docs.rs/rug/1.17.0/rug/float/fn.prec_max.html).

Are you sure you need 2147483647 bits of precision? I suspect you don't. Keep in mind a normal double has 53 bits of precision. So you are asking for more than a million times more precision. *The precision isn't the max number you can represented but the number of bits used to store the value*.

> In particular, with a precision of 53 bits, mpfr should be able to exactly reproduce all computations with double-precision machine floating-point numbers (double type in C)

If you really want max precision do:

```
use rug::{Complete, Float, Integer};
let _num = Integer::from(103204);
let _float = Float::with_val(u32::MAX, _num);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I need about 35 trillion digits after the decimal,

Comment: is that possible here in rust rug?

Comment: 35trillion digits. Let's call it 3 bits to a digit (conservative) 105T bits. (105000000000000)/8/1024/1024/1024/1024 gives us 12 Terabytes min to store that number. Do you even have that much disk space?

Comment: yes i have about 60 tb to work with!

Comment: so it is not possible to get more precision that the max value for an i32?

Comment: @HadiB I fear so...

Comment: That sucks :/, but thank you both for your responses. Are there any alternative for this?

Comment: @HadiB It's still hard to understand what problem you are solving. Are you really trying to represent a number that takes 12 terabytes to store? How much memory do you have? Even with 60 terabytes of memory, you'll only be able to store 5 such numbers (at best). What are you doing?

Comment: Computing very large constants

Comment: @HadiB tell us more. What will you do with them once you have them? What is the constant?

Comment: its pi and its for a school project